# Use tab to jump to NextMark in TeXshop

Tags: editors, texshop, macos

Is it possible to use 'tab' to jump to the next mark in TeXshop? I know how to change it in setting as 'command'+'something'. BTW, I use 'esc' as auto-commpletion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opt-Esc ancd Ctl-Esc will also move between marks when Esc is the trigger for Command Completion. If you set Tab as the trigger then you can use Opt-Tab and Ctl-Tab for moving between marks. This is in addition to the standard Ctl-Cmd-F and Ctl-Cmd-G in either case of course.